# Problems with overlapping elements and visiblity

Tags: html, css

Hey I've created a navbar and I've added an illusionary marker effect under it.

Basically what I want it to do is for when i hover over the image for an arrow to display under it.

Unfortunately I can't quite get it to work.

In the illustration below, I want to showcase. This is how the arrows are placed. Basically, I've set the second one on `visibility: hidden;` and for illustration purposes left the rest visible.

The one that has black background shows the one I'm hovering my cursor over (showcasing the selection works, there just must be something wrong with my css implementation). I've set the background as #000 (black) only for illustration purposes of the hover. As for the actual code, i just wish for the image to be visible.

[image]

So once again, what I want **is for the arrows to stay hidden unless you hover over them**. My code looks something like this

```
<div class = "arrows">
  <img src="" class="1" alt =""><img src="" class="2" alt =""
  <img..et cetera>
</div>
```

As for the actual CSS, I have some margin and padding set up which is not really of importance.

Basically the important part is:

```
.arrows img {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 20px;
}
```

and now for the specific arrows

```
img.1 {
  visiblity:hidden;
  margin, padding and few other properties
}

img.1:hover {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

However, when I hover over the image, it just remains invisible. Any ideas how to solve this?

---

**EDIT:** Added code snippet/jsfiddle

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
body,
div,
span,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
a {
  font-family: Arial;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*
====================================================
NAVIGACNY PANEL
====================================================
*/

.navbar {
  background-color: #3c1f0a;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}
.navbar ul {
  z-index: -1;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 175px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.navbar li {
  width: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
.navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
}
.navbar li:hover {
  background-color: #602401;
}
/*
=============================================================
KRATKY POPIS - Index
=============================================================
*/

.ITW {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background: rgb(252, 255, 251);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(252, 255, 251, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 250, 1) 1%, rgba(255, 253, 255, 1) 1%, rgba(252, 252, 252, 1) 20%, rgba(250, 250, 250, 1) 21%, rgba(248, 248, 248, 1) 31%, rgba(246, 246, 246, 1) 32%, rgba(247, 247, 247, 1) 35%, rgba(233, 233, 233, 1) 73%, rgba(234, 234, 234, 1) 75%, rgba(232, 232, 232, 1) 76%, rgba(227, 227, 227, 1) 100%);
}
.ITW img {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px 15px 10px 17px;
  bottom: 20px;
}
.ITW img:hover {
  position: relative;
  visibility: visible;
}
img.move-image {
  margin-left: 190px;
}
img.ma {
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
img .ma:hover {
  visibility: visible;
}
img.mb {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
img.mc {
  padding-right: 30px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
img.md {
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
img.me {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
img.mf {
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.ITW h2 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 19px;
  padding: 10px 0px 15px 0px;
  color: #b15e23;
  margin-left: 200px;
}
.ITW p {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #656565;
  margin-left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#ITW">Index</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#ITW">O predmete</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#Lectures">Prednášky</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#Results">Výsledky</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#Exercises">Cvičenia</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#Contact">Kontakt</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#Related">Related</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="ITW">
    <img src="icons/menu_bullet.gif" class="move-image" alt="moved-bullet">
    <img src="icons/menu_bullet.gif" class="ma" alt="index-bullet">
    <img src="icons/menu_bullet.gif" class="mb" alt="index-bullet">
    <img src="icons/menu_bullet.gif" class="mc" alt="index-bullet">
    <img src="icons/menu_bullet.gif" class="md" alt="index-bullet">
    <img src="icons/menu_bullet.gif" class="me" alt="index-bullet">
    <img src="icons/menu_bullet.gif" class="mf" alt="index-bullet">
  </div>
```

Comment: a fiddle woud be easy to solve this

Comment: @Rawrplus you have fixed .navbar li {  width: 80px; } it should be auto to avoid the same

Comment: Also, I switched visiblity: hidden; and visisibility: visisible to opacity: 0; and opacity: 1; and it did the trick, although it's kind of a silly work-around the issue rather than tackling it head on.

Comment: @Rawrplus The problem is that you can't hover over a hidden element

Comment: your image/arrow is initially hidden hence you cant hover on that (you cant  fire events on element which are hidden)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize, I've realized that if I set the visibility to `hidden;` you can't hover over the element since it's hidden from you.

The easiest solution  instead of using the `visibility:` attribute, use the `opacity:` attribute is well and switch it between 0 and 1(hover).

Answer (score 2):

Grabs wrench*, tingling sounds*
Background music with low volume rock {ace of spades};

Try and set the navbar with:

```
z-index:2;
position: relative;
```

Set the arrows with:

```
Z-index:1;
position: relative;
```

By setting a higher value of `Z-index` your creating a layer type logic: the higher the value the upper the layer will be set;
all objects affected with z-index must have position attribute;